# "Count where" in a collection

Tags: lodash

Using lodash, what would be a good way to count the number of objects in a collection conditionally? Say I wanted to count the number of objects where

```
a < 4
```

in the following collection

```
[{a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}, {a : 4}, {a : 5}, {a : 6}]
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Below you can find an easy way to achieve that using the [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) method:

```
var b = _.filter(a, function(o) { if (o.a < 4) return o }).length;
```

Comment: Downvoted because this method unnecessarily builds an entire new Array (from `filter`) just to count objects.

Comment: Sure @WizardofOgz, but then suggest an alternate way then before downvoting. How would you do it?

Comment: I _did_ suggest a better alternative by up-voting Gunar C. Gessner's answer. ;-)

Answer (score 61):

### Solution

You can use [`countBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy):

```
const total = _.countBy(
    array,
    ({ a }) => a < 4 ? 'lessThanFour' : 'greaterThanFour'
  ).lessThanFour
```

### Alternative

Using [`sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sumBy):

```
const total = _.sumBy(
  array,
  ({ a }) => Number(a < 4)
);
```

And here's the same but with [`lodash/fp`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```
const count = _.sumBy(_.flow(_.get('a'), _.lt(4), Number), objects);
```

Comment: The official documentation doesn't do a good job of explaining the possibilities you are showing here, so thank you. I still think this answer could be improved if the example code were explained, though.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [_.countBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#countBy):

`const count = _.countBy(arr, o => o.a < 4).true`